# groupadd / useradd command fails to give user write access to `$HOME/x`

Tags: shell, ubuntu, docker, debian, sh

I am getting this `sh` error when building a Docker image:

```
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
```

it's arriving after an npm install command, otherwise I don't have much more context for it. Does anyone know how I might figure out where the error originates from? Can I debug `sh` somehow?

Or perhaps I can override `sh` with `bash` and then try to debug bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ltrace** command can be used to trace library calls. So

```
ltrace -e 'getcwd'
```

could do the job.

A sample output could be:

```
$ ltrace -e getcwd ./test                                             
test->getcwd(0x7ffd3e148700, 1024) = "/home/user/temp"                   
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```